# Upload files to a specific folder from a form

Tags: google-forms, google-apps, google-app-maker

I am a teacher with limited coding knowledge. I am trying to create a google app script so that my students can upload documents from a form. on the form, the student will choose their name from a droplist and I would like the script to upload the documents in the folder with the same name that I have previously created on my drive.

I found this script which allows uploading the file to a specific folder based on the folder id. How could I modify it to upload to different folder ids based on the name they have chosen on the form?

```
function myFunction (e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  // I modified below script.
  Utilities.sleep(3000);

  var folderId = "1dNoanQMGXvBDIsIRITNHCXnP8srW_Wlt";  // Please set folder ID of the destination folder.

  var destfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    if (itemResponses[i].getItem().getType() == "FILE_UPLOAD") {
      var ids = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
      for (var j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ids[j]);
        destfolder.addFile(file);
        file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the result I was looking for by adding a switch function to the script. hope it might help others....

```
function myFunction (e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  // I modified below script.
  Utilities.sleep(3000);

  var items = e.response.getItemResponses()
  var name = items[0].getResponse();
  
Logger.log('result is: ' + name);
  
   var parentFolderId = '';
  switch (name) {
    case 'Red':
      parentFolderId = "1JBHIj9BcR-_LDLSwU2nNLo1u5v0sWaAT";
      break;
    case 'Blue':
      parentFolderId = "1NkRQnMxaT2ZFOuLzKk7lc-pZt-OVlPhc";
      break;
    case 'Green':
      parentFolderId = "12EMeWGRwNnf3uE-JkhTmXxznX0OLL60V";
      break;
  }
  Logger.log('Switch result is: ' + parentFolderId);
  
  
  
  var folderId = parentFolderId ;  // Please set folder ID of the destination folder.

  var destfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    if (itemResponses[i].getItem().getType() == "FILE_UPLOAD") {
      var ids = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
      for (var j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ids[j]);
        destfolder.addFile(file);
        file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: AppMaker is going to be stopped by the end of the month (Jan 2021), you should consider other technologies for your apps (like AppSheet) ;-)